# How to manage initialisation code of dependencies for tests

Tags: unit-testing, go, logging

I have a log wrapper (uses logrus implementation underneath) and I’m using this package to log across my app. The way I do this is by passing the logger variable to each of the required packages through dependency injection.

Here, when writing test cases for each of the packages, I have to write some code to initialise the logger package. How do we avoid having to write initialisation code for the test cases of every package which uses the logger?

logger/log.go

```golang
type Logger interface {
    Info(args ...interface{})
    Infof(format string, keyvals ...any)
    InfoWithFields(fields map[string]interface{}, msg ...interface{})

    Debug(args ...interface{})
    Debugf(format string, keyvals ...any)
    DebugWithFields(fields map[string]interface{}, msg ...interface{})
}
```

app_test.go

```
func setupLogrusLogger() (*bytes.Buffer, Logger) {
    buf := &bytes.Buffer{}
    logrusLogger := log.New()
    logrusLogger.Out = buf
    logrusLogger.Formatter = &log.JSONFormatter{}
    return buf, NewLogrusLogger(logrusLogger)
}

func TestSomething(t *testing.T) {
  // buf can be used to inspect what gets logged if required
  buf, logger := setupLogrusLogger()
  Something(logger)
}
```

Here, for each of the packages which uses logger, I'd have to initialise the logger by defining something similar to `setupLogrusLogger`. Is there any way to avoid having to write this separately for each package I'm writing tests for?

Comment: Not directly related to your question, but my first piece of advice would be not to set up a full-fledged logger for tests, and instead use the test logger provided by logrus: https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/sirupsen/logrus/hooks/test#NewNullLogger

Comment: @JonathanHall As you mentioned, this does not answer my question. However this is very useful information, where the tests does not have to care what gets logged.

The reason I did not use null logger provided by logrus is because I've copied the above code from the test case for the log package I've written and hence I wanted to inspect the things which gets logged.

Comment: *"Is there any way to avoid having to write this separately for each package I'm writing tests for?"* -- Export the dependency initializing function (and declare it in a non-`_test.go` file) so that the other packages can import and reuse it. If you'd like to separate the test logic from the package's normal code you can move the initializing function to a "test util" package.

Comment: @mkopriva I've considered both the approaches you mentioned.
Moving the dependency initialising code as an exported function means we're added something which is not used for the app to run in a non-test file. Other problem with this approach is that it would not be covered by code coverage, since it does not make much sense to add a test for this function.

Regarding creation of util package, I try to avoid them. There are some [good reads](https://dave.cheney.net/2019/01/08/avoid-package-names-like-base-util-or-common) regarding why it's considered a bad practice.

Comment: @albin I haven't read the linked article in full, but the title says _"Avoid package names ..."_. I didn't say anything about how you should name that package. There's a number of "test util" packages in the standard library (e.g. `net/http/httptest`, `net/internal/socktest`) and there's a number of non-test utility packages as well (e.g. `net/http/httputil`, `io/ioutil`). Utility packages are completely fine they are not a bad practice, how you name them and what you drop into them is another matter.

Comment: *"means we're added something which is not used for the app to run in a non-test file."* -- How is this a problem? Are you worried about the size of the binary? If so then you don't need to be, dead code (code not used by the actual program) will be removed during compilation.

Comment: @mkopriva Got it, this is what I was looking for. I guess I simply have to change the mindset. The examples you provided cleared them up for me. Thanks!

If you could add this as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: @albin: It's useful when you do care what gets logged, too. The `LastEntry` and `AllEntries` methods on the NullLogger hook give you that information.

Comment: @JonathanHall Yes, just looked at the hook mechanism and it seems I do not have to override the logrus logger implementation to check what gets logged. As you mentioned, the hooks does that job as expected and I've currently replaced my internal implementation of the hooks functionality with the in-build hook provided by the NewNullLogger. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Export the dependency initializing function and declare it in a non-`_test.go` file so that the other packages can import and reuse it. If you'd like to separate the test logic from the package's normal code you can move the initializing function to a package that provides utilities for testing.

And, as long as you import such test-utility packages only from within `_test.go` files (and not from normal files), the test utility code won't make it into the actual program's compiled binary.

---

Examples of such test-utility packages can be found in the standard library:

[`net/http/httptest`](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http/httptest@go1.20.4)

> Package httptest provides utilities for HTTP testing.

[`net/internal/socktest`](https://pkg.go.dev/net/internal/socktest@go1.20.4)

> Package socktest provides utilities for socket testing.

[`os/exec/internal/fdtest`](https://pkg.go.dev/os/exec/internal/fdtest@go1.20.4)

> Package fdtest provides test helpers for working with file descriptors across exec.

[`testing/quick`](https://pkg.go.dev/testing/quick@go1.20.4)

> Package quick implements utility functions to help with black box testing.

[`testing/fstest`](https://pkg.go.dev/testing/fstest@go1.20.4)

> Package fstest implements support for testing implementations and users of file systems.

[`testing/iotest`](https://pkg.go.dev/testing/iotest@go1.20.4)

> Package iotest implements Readers and Writers useful mainly for testing.